# How to show value from negative to positive in mpandroid barchart?

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I'm using mpandroid barchart and I have set negative and positive value in it but I want to that in barchart values start from -100 to 0 and 0 to 10, 20 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help your issue, but try [setAxisMinimum()](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.1.0/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/AxisBase.html#setAxisMinimum-float-).

Also note, as per the documentation:

`Do not forget to call setStartAtZero(false) if you use this method. Otherwise, the axis-minimum value will still be forced to 0.`

Comment: setStartAtZero(false) is deprecated method.